# How to change TextInputLayout border color when empty or any validation

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

[image]

Please, I want to change border color of TextInputLayout when error or empty as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **`boxStrokeErrorColor`** attribute:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
          app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/..."
          ..>
```

**Note:** this requires at least the version **`1.2.0`**.

Or you can use the `setBoxStrokeColorStateList` method:

```
textInputLayout.setBoxStrokeColorStateList(.....);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, but it doesn't change anyway, simply i want to set error onClick button while Login

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:boxStrokeErrorColor="@color/yourBorderColor">

    ...

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

You can read more about this [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/#container-attributes-1).

Comment: Thanks man, but it doesn't change anyway, simply i want to set error onClick button while Login